# Can each machine learning algorithm be summarized to one formula?

Tags: machine-learning

I have just started studying about machine learning, I know its an ocean in itself. Just wondering if each machine learning algorithm be summarized by a formula?

Comment: The question is how you define Formula? Is for example f(x,a) = x if a==0 and -x if a!=0. Then the next question would be would you restrict towards finite formula?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, machine learning so far is backed by math and statistics, so in a sense, yes.

Difficulty relies on choosing the right formulas, variables and so forth, applied to what you want to "learn", so yes, but at the same time, don't expect magic formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning includes three large branches, namely *supervised learning*, *unsupervised learning* and *reinforcement learning*. Each has a different setup, requirements and goals.

An attempt to summarize all three to one formula is like summarizing algebra, geometry and calculus to one formula. So a precise answer to your question is *"Of course, not"*.

But still, I think that you might had just *supervised learning* in mind, so I can do some hand waving to help your intuition. In essence, machine learning is about *approximating the joint distribution of data* (sounds scary, but that's what you asked - one formula).

Let me give you an example: there is a big space of images and a big space of labels ("cat", "car", ...). Both of these spaces are random: some images are naturally more frequent than others (roughly speaking) and for each image there is a distribution of its labels. You might think that there is always one and only one label per image, but it's fairly possible to be unsure about the true label. A Bayesian way of formalizing this uncertainty is through probability. Together these probability spaces, `Images` and `Labels`, form a [joint distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) `p(Images, Labels)`.

Now, the true distribution is unknown to us, but we are attempting to "learn" it, at least a conditional `p(Labels|Images)` (recognition) or a joint ([generation](https://github.com/junyanz/iGAN)). "Learning" here is an iterative process of approximation, when each step is getting closer and closer to the target. One more complication is that we are given only a finite sample from both spaces and thus have to extrapolate our distribution in new regions (it's called *generalization*).

That's basically a probabilistic view upon machine learning. If you are interested, this idea is discussed in much greater detail in the first chapters of [this book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387310732) and gives some impression of what a machine learning is in general.